# Syncronous waiting for a Future or a Stream to complete in Dart

Tags: dart

I'm playing with a tiny web server and I'm implementing one version using the `async` package, and one synchronous version executing each request in a separate *isolate*. I would like to simply pipe a file stream to the `HttpResponse`, but I can't do that synchronously. And I can't find a way to wait for neither the `Stream` nor a `Future` synchronously. I'm now using a `RandomAccessFile` instead which works, but it becomes messier.

One solution would be to execute a periodical timer to check if the future is completed (by setting a boolean or similar), but that is most definitely not something I want to use.

Is there a way to wait synchronously for a `Future` and a `Stream`? If not, why?

Answer (score 3):

For future visitors coming here simply wanting to perform some task after a Future or Stream completes, use `await` and `await for` inside an async method.

### Future

```
final myInt = await getFutureInt();
```

### Stream

```
int mySum = 0;
await for (int someInt in myIntStream) {
  mySum += someInt;
}
```

### Note

This may be technically different than performing a synchronous task, but it achieves the goal of completing one task before doing another one.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there isn't a way to wait synchronously for a Future or a Stream. Why? Because these are asynchronous pretty much definitionally, and as you are discovering, the APIs are designed with asynchronous behavior in mind.

There are a couple of Future constructors, `Future.value()` and `Future.sync()`, that execute immediately, but I don't think these are probably what you have in mind.

Comment: Sure they are asynchronous, but if I want to use a stream in a separate isolate there are good reasons to wait for completion. Asynchronous code is simply more complex. And given the APIs provided it seems as the dart team wants to provide a good foundation for synchronous programming. A simple `T get({timeout: Duration})` would do it in the Future case. Streams would require some more. Thus, saying that they are by definition asynchronous does not explain it.

Comment: "Asynchronous code is simply more complex" - agree completely. And sometimes you DO just have to wait for something to complete before continuing.

Comment: I think I read in discussions that this is planned but will take some time. See also https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=104